# How to add a validation in azure data factory pipeline to check file size?

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I have multiple data sources I want to add a validation in azure data factory before loading into tables it should check for file size so that it is not empty. So if the file size is more than 10 kb or if it is not empty loading should start and if it is empty then loading should not start.
I checked validation activity in Azure Data Factory but it is not showing size for multiple files in a folder.
Any suggestions appreciated basically if I can add any python notebook for this validation will also do.

Answer (score 3):

Following GIF shows step by step process on how to achieve the above requirement in ADF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetMetadata` under General Activities, then send the result to an `If Condition`.
[image: Get Metadata for File]

You will then need to get the file size from the Dataset.`@item().name` is the name of the file you want to get the size of.
[image: Get File Size]

If you are working with a directory do the following:
[image: Get Metadata for content of folder]

[image: Get child items]
Then check the file size of each file.

This is what the ForEach settings looks like. Then you can use `@item().name` inside the ForEach to get at the file.

[image: For Each Settings]

The data source will need to have the parameter FileName.
[image: Parameters for Datasource]

Comment: I added the above but for each activity unable to get the file size. Can you show what how to get the file size in for each activity

Comment: @SHIBASHISHTRIPATHY did you use the GetMetadata to get each child item from the directory? Then inside the ForEach did you use the GetMetadata to request the size of each file?

Comment: @JSWilson how can you use GetMetadata on each file? GetMetadata activity only takes a dataset in its settings

Comment: @JSWilson I read more carefully your answer, there was it :)